# Persistance in bootable Ubuntu USB

Tags: boot, usb, mac, display-resolution, settings

I have a bootable USB with Ubuntu 16.04.
I use it in my mac but every time I reboot, I lose all settings Ive made. (resolution, wifi password, files, etc)
What can i do to fix it? Also I cannot access to Macintosh to save files there.
Sorry for my english, im from Argentina.

Comment: How big is the USB?  Can you just recreate it with persistence?  Are you booting UEFI or legacy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't understand you well, but I think that you're trying to say is that you want to make your USB work like an Ubuntu portable installation.

Try to follow [this guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx), **but set the "space used to preserve files across reboots" the space you want to have.**
(e.g. if you want to have 1 GB space, put there 1024)

I hope this works.